# How do I transfer my Watch settings to an additional Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I understand how to transfer Watch settings to a new Watch [while unpairing the old watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251918/4395). Is there a way to transfer settings while adding the new watch as and *additional* paired watch? Can I copy the settings from my old watch to the new one while keeping the old one paired?

Comment: FWIW, this scenario seems not to really be supported. Although it appears the transfer can be achieved, it takes quite some time for a change of watches to be recognized (for the purpose of unlocking).

Comment: Actually this is supported. Make one backup and restore it to both watches.